# R-studio installation for ubuntu 16.04 32-bit

Tags: rstudio, ubuntu-16.04

I have problems with R-studio installation for Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit. I found out a reason for my problem here - https://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/installing-r-studio-on-ubuntu-16-10/. But the script examples are for 64-bit machine and I don't quite understand how I can change them for my 32-bit machine. 
Does somebody had the same problems? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

o Install R 3.4.1 and Rstudio on ubuntu 16.04 LTS on 32 bit machine :

Carry out following steps :

> cd $HOME
>
> wget https://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/R-3.4.1.tar.gz
>
> tar xvf R-3.4.1.tar.gz
>
> cd R-3.4.1
>
> sudo apt-get install gcc fort77 aptitude
>
> sudo aptitude install g++
>
> sudo aptitude install xorg-dev
>
> sudo aptitude install libreadline-dev
>
> sudo aptitude install gfortran
>
> gfortran --version
>
> sudo apt install libpcre3-dev liblzma-dev libbz2-dev
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
>
> sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
>
> sudo apt-get install texlive-base
>
> sudo apt-get install texinfo
>
> sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
>
> sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
>
> sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libpng-dev zlib1g-dev libpixman-1-dev libxt-dev
>
> java -version

## need to build shared library (--enable-R-shlib)

## the --enable-R-shlib option is needed for the RStudio IDE to work

> sudo ./configure --enable-R-shlib
>
> sudo make
>
> sudo make install
>
> R --version
>
> cd $HOME
>
> rm R-3.4.1.tar.gz
>
> sudo rm -rf R-3.4.1

Only one warning is shown during compilation:

main.c: In function ‘dummy_ii’:

main.c:1669:12: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return (uintptr_t) ⅈ

```
        ^
```

Now you can install Rstudio (here for a 32 bits system; choose the correct one for you here https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/):

> sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
>
> wget https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-1.0.143-i386.deb
>
> sudo gdebi -n rstudio-1.0.143-i386.deb
>
> rm rstudio-1.0.143-i386.deb

To know if you have a 32-bits or 64-bits system, enter:
uname -a

The machine hardware name lists whether your system is 32-bit (“i686” or “i386”) or 64-bit (“x86_64”).

For further details refer the link : 
https://biostatsr.blogspot.in/2017/06/install-r-340-and-rstudio-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems current versions of RStudio in Ubuntu 16.04 are not supported for 32-bit. So I enabled i386 architecture (https://blog.teststation.org/ubuntu/2016/05/12/installing-32-bit-software-on-ubuntu-16.04/) in order to install previous Ubuntu 32-bit versions.

```
    sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Then I was able to install RStudio 1.1.442 - Ubuntu 12.04-15.10/Debian 8 (32-bit) (https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-1.1.442-i386.deb). It worked for my Xubuntu 16.04 (32-bit)